# django query for counting number of records based on hour from datetime field

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a model named Log which have datetime field named "datetime". 
I want to have number of records based on daily, yearly, hourly etc.

**for yearly  count I have used**

```
Log.objects.extra({'date_creat' : "date(datetime)"}).values('date_creat').annotate(total= Count('date'))
```

Now how can I filter hour from the datetime field. Is there any method that extracts hour from datetime field as `date(datetime)` extract date from the datetime within extra fields.

Comment: The `extra(...)` executes a function in straight SQL. So it depends on the database that you are using. In the case of Postgres it would be `date_trunc('hour', datetime)`

Comment: I am using sqlite database